# Error in html file with javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

I am beginning to experience the fabulous world of Javascript, I am making a html file with a javascript function with a box, the fact is that the alert does not show what goes into the text field, what am I doing wrong ?, this is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function showMe()
        {
            var nombre= cnombre.value;
            alert("You are "+ nombre);
            cnombre.value="";
            cnombre.focus();
        }
        </script>
    </head> 

    <body>  
            Name:<input type ="text" name="cnombre" 
    size="30">
            <input type="button" value="Go"
    onClick=showMe();>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed your code to give the textbox an id and then retrieve the textbox from the DOM by that id.  This should work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    function showMe() {
    var nombre = document.getElementById('cnombre');
    alert("You are " + nombre.value);
    nombre.value = "";
    nombre.focus();
}
    </script>
</head> 

<body>  
        Name:<input type ="text" id="cnombre" name="cnombre" 
size="30">
        <input type="button" value="Go"
onClick=showMe();>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the textbox like that. See http://jsfiddle.net/GUB3E/ for a working sample based on your code.

Note the `id="cnombre"` added to the textbox and the use of `document.getElementById()`.